# AJAX Request from Phonegap Android fails

Tags: android, cordova

I have been working on this for the last two days, and looking at a lot of other suggestions. Yes I can get this simple ajax request to work from within a phonegap application, both on the android emulator and on an actual android phone.

My phonegap version is (using phonegap -v) 3.0.0-0.14.3

The code I'm using is:

```
var url = 'http://www.thomas-bayer.com/sqlrest/CUSTOMER';
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        timeout: 60 * 1000
    }).done(function (data) {
        alert('hey');
    }).fail(function (a, b, c) {
        console.log(b + '|' + c);
    });
```

The result I'm getting in the log is just:

> error| at file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js:62

I added the settings to the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

and I have the following in Config.xml

```
<param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.core.NetworkManager" />
```

When I check `navigator.connection.type` I get `3G` on the emulator and `wifi` on the physical phone.

Any idea what else could go wrong?

**UPDATE:**
If I log the JSON in the first parameter of the failing function I get:

```
{"readyState":4,"status":404,"statusText":"error"}
```

Comment: Does the same page load (the one that makes this ajax request) correctly in the stock browser, or a plain WebView?

Comment: @FoamyGuy I just had the same thought. Added jquery to set the same url on a page <a> tag. Clicking on it opens then browser (on the phone) and the page loads successfully

Comment: Are you using any other javascript on your pages? WebView by default disables support for javascript. I'm not terribly familiar with phonegap so I don't know whether it passes the choice of whether or not to enable the javascript down to you via some config/setup option or something. But if it does then you'd have to make sure that it is set to allow javascript. If however you have other javascript on your page (or another page in your app) and it works fine then it must be already enabled.

Comment: @FoamyGuy Javascript works fine. And I'm not using a WebView. It is just the ajax that is failing

Comment: BTW I also gave it a try with a pure XMLHttpRequest request. Also fails

Comment: if you are rendering html/css/javascript then you are using a webview =) phone gap is just handling it for you. If the rest of your javascript works fine though then I don't know where else to point you. Which line is 62?

Comment: @FoamyGuy 62 is the line with the `console.log`

Comment: Are you remembering to whitelist the domain?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You should [whitelist](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html) the domain in order for your AJAX calls to work.

Add this line to config file -:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

Phonegap's default policy blocks all network access unless specified otherwise. The above line will disable this security restriction. You can also be more specific in allowing only certain domains to bypass this security feature by including the domain name in the config file like so

```
<access origin="http://yourdomain" />
```

Comment: Sooo glad to see this at 4 in the morning.

Answer (score 16):

additionally to the whitelisting, make sure the cors flag is true to enable cross origin resource sharing.

```
$.support.cors=true;
```

please find the reference [here](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0/docs/pages/phonegap.html)

Comment: akiva i love you. good job. whitelist alone didn't work. had to set this to true on page load!

Answer (score 0):

I had a localhost url as I was using Visual Studio.
I resolved by editing the VS projects Applicationhost.config file and making a version of the binding protocol so that is it *:port:* not *:port:localhost, and then accessing via ip address. 
Make sure to get all references to the port.