# Ajax request working in browsers but not in phonegap

Tags: php, ajax, cordova

I have a cross domain request working perfectly within firefox, chrome etc
as soon as i compile with phonegap it stops working

Ajax:

```
 function createCORSRequest(method, url){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if ("withCredentials" in xhr){
        xhr.open(method, url, true);
    } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined"){
        xhr = new XDomainRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url);
    } else {
        xhr = null;
    }
    return xhr;
}

var request = createCORSRequest("get", "http://www.sellfast.co.za/get.php");
if (request){
    request.onload = function(){
        document.body.innerHTML = request.responseText;
    } 
    request.send();
}
```

This code rewrites the body hmtl and just shows the result text fetched from the server.
I did this simply for testing. it does nothing once running in phonegap

this is get.php on the server:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
echo "Hello world";
?>
```

I added this to the phonegap config.xml:

```
<access origin="*" subdomains="true" />
```

But it still didnt change anything

Any idea why this isnt working?

Best Regards,

Jason

Comment: Try to wait for the deviceready event before you start the request.

Comment: you know what... that might work. ill get back to you on this.

Comment: That works in the emulator but not when i run it on the android device?

Answer (score 0):

in phonegap to use ajax, you must whitelist a particular domain, you can read all about it here
[click here to visit page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18263578/ajax-request-from-phonegap-android-fails)

Comment: i have done this. i added the whitelist to the config.xml file already and it didnt work