# webscraping using Phonegap

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I need to build a cross-platform app (IOS + Android) that requires some web scraping capabilities.
 What I need it to do is to login on certain sites, grab the relevant information and present a combined overview of data from these sites.

So is there any way to accomplish web scraping in phonegap?

Comment: same question bro....!!

Answer (score 1):

It's easy, just use Ajax to request a page.

Use something like JQuery to make the Ajax easier to work with.

Use JavaScript's regular expressions to extract what you want from the Ajax response.  You could also use a Dom parser library of some sort as well for more direct access.

Make sure you have your PhoneGap config set up correctly for making Ajax requests.  See [AJAX Request from Phonegap Android fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18263578/ajax-request-from-phonegap-android-fails)