# 403 Forbidden response from jQuery.ajax request with PhoneGap Desktop

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova, http-status-code-403

I set up a PhoneGap Project and start it up via PhoneGap Desktop.
In this Project I call the following jQuery method:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://api.fixer.io/latest',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            exchangeRates = data;
            displayData(exchangeRates);
        }
    })
```

Once I fire it using a button I get a 403 "Forbidden" response.
The requested URL is: http://192.168.178.40:3000/proxy/http://api.fixer.io/latest

Which is the local Serveradress (192.168.178.40:3000) where PhoneGap Desktop loads up the App and a proxy, this seems to come from PhoneGap aswell.
The sent request header looks like this:

```
Host: 192.168.178.40:3000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://192.168.178.40:3000/
Cookie: connect.sid=s%3AhoA3oe0JbAdmGQ4Z6bYlRuFa.oDM1qjeHCadzwfSmYy%2BFabG0b22OH0ZqRgVuLMlcCL8
Connection: keep-alive
```

And the response header as following:

```
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/plain
Date: Fri, 20 Nov 2015 12:07:23 GMT
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Status: 403 Forbidden
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

When I try to open the requested URL, it delivers the JSON I wanted.

Why do I get the 403? Can anybody help?

**[EDIT after Success]**
Ok seems like I had a problem within the PhoneGap Project I set up, since 
[Simon Pricketts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5338708/simon-prickett) suggestion seemed right.
 
So I set up a completely new Project. This time a straight Cordova 5.4.0 Project without the PhoneGap overlay. Then I tried Simons suggestion again and voilà ---> Success this time!

Conclusion: Somehow the config.xml of the PhoneGap Project in combination with the Content-Security-Policy led to an hiccup in the App, which resulted in the 403 Error. And since I was less familiar with PhoneGap I tried straight Cordova, which worked.

Comment: _it delivers the JSON I wanted_ absolutely but if you see the console you can find the actual issue. one solution is to have a response of json with a padding means `jsonp` for crossdomain data sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to set up a Content Security Policy meta tag if using Cordova 5, and additionally configure App Transport Security if using iOS9 or when you move the app to iOS in the future.

I have a blog post that demonstrates how to do this and actually also uses the same data source you are trying to use - you can read this [here](http://moduscreate.com/cordova-5-ios-9-security-policy-changes/).

You would need something like this in your index.html if this is your issue:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; connect-src http://api.fixer.io">
```

Note: connect-src clause which specifies access to http://api.fixer.io

Comment: This would be needed in addition to the `<access origin="*"/>` or similar in your project config.xml

Comment: This seems like a good option. I tried the (explicit) whitelisting suggestion but that didn't seem like the hole answer. 
Now I'll see if your answer helps me. Thanks so far.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely haven't [whitelisted](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html) the domain you're trying to access. As explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18263578/ajax-request-from-phonegap-android-fails), before connecting to an "external" domain, you need to whitelist it.

And just so that we have the answer here as well: you need to add this to your configuration file:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

Comment: Actually I already had this in my config.xml. Still it doesn't work. I'll try the explicit whitelisting.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, so far it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

In Post Cordova 5 I believe you need to include the whitelist as a plug in in the config.xml file like this:

```
<access origin="http://*.phonegap.com" subdomains="true" />
<access origin="*://*.api.fixer.io/*" subdomains="true" />

<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" />
```

If you want to include external files into the window from external sources or ajax calls you will need to include the plugin this way