# Phonegap App retrieve data on PC but not on Android device

Tags: android, phonegap

I am writing a PhoneGap application but I found some problems.
I scrape some data from a web page and show the result in the html body.
The problem is that this works well on PC but not in my android device.
I use the PhoneGap Build tool to generate my .APK file. When I install the app the content are correctly shown, but if the online content changes just on the PC i spot them and in the device they seem "freeze". I've added a button to force the reload but this doesn't work. 
I read somewhere that the ajax call are blocked on device if you don't have the developer key..is this true ?

I also tried to add the white-list plugin to my app ( I know it's deprecated ) but nothing.

Thanks in advance ! :)

Comment: Did you try other options? See for example [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-xdk/topic/743093) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18263578/ajax-request-from-phonegap-android-fails).

Comment: The links you provided are the same that I saw before to write the question. 
For this reason I've asked if the dev-key is important to make ajax-calls works.
My ajax-calls don't give me error. It just works when I run the first time the app, then it seems to not work anymore ( the contents in my <body> tag don't change.