# What do I have to change to run a normal Ajax in PhoneGap?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, cordova, phonegap

I want to make an Ajax request in a PhoneGap application.
I tried it with my normal website code which runs perfectly fine but in PhoneGap nothing happened when I pressed the button which should start the Ajax.
Does anyone know what i have to change on the code or other settings in PhoneGap?

This is my Ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "https://qurusre.de/Marksutus.N.php",
      data: {nummer: nummer,status: status,IdSchueler:IdSchueler,},
      success: function(data) {}
})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AJAX Request from Phonegap Android fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18263578/ajax-request-from-phonegap-android-fails)

Comment: @mitkosoft i will try it if it works i will delete this question thx

Comment: @mitkosoft it doesnt answer my question i have enabled it but nothing changed

Comment: you need both `<access origin>` and `$.support.cors=true;`

Comment: @mitkosoft where can i enable this?

Comment: @mitkosoft where is the place to implement $.support.. i don't get it